# Entity Framework function/stored proc updates

Tags: entity-framework, stored-functions

If i change the the underlying storedproc of a function and update the complex type; does the entire model have to updated as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually just delete the proc from my model, and then "update the model from the database", but only selecting the proc that was changed.